# How to get sub-categories of a specific parent category in Flask?

Tags: flask

I can't get a sub-categories in my `nav-menu`.

I've created relationship between them **one-to-many**, here is the two **models**:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    slug = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)
    subs = db.relationship('Sub', backref='categories', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Category: {}".format(self.name)

class Sub(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    slug = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)

    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Sub: {}".format(self.name)
```

inside the view i used a basic query to grab them all ,here is the **view**

```
categories = Category.query.join(Sub, Sub.name == Category)
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).one()

    login_user(user)

    identity_changed.send(
        current_app._get_current_object(),
        identity=Identity(user.id)
    )
    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('main.index'))
return render_template('index.html', form=form, all_category=categories)
```

In index.html i used a **jinja2** `for loop` to sort them in my `nav-menu`, here is the code:

```
{% for categories in all_category %}
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{categories.name}} <span class="count pull-right">{{categories.subs.count()}}</span></a>
        <ul class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">{{categories.subs.name}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

What i get is just the **category name** and the count of there **subs** .

Please , anybody can tell me if i made any mistake and where ???

Comment: Hmm, don't you need another loop over categories.subs in the jinja template?

Comment: I tried , without a val :( !

Comment: Is there any other relation that i had to add ??

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
categories = db.session.query(Category, Sub).filter(Category.id == Sub.category_id).all()
```